# sinatra - Using get and post to display user input

Tags: sinatra

I am new to Sinatra. I want the user in my home page to submit a word to my translate page and see the word displayed in the translate page. This is not happening and I do not know why. I would greatly appreciate any help.
This is the code for my home page:

```
<form action="/translate" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="message">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This is the code for my main page:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/reloader' if development?

get "/home" do 
    erb :home
end

post "/translate" do
    params[:message]
    erb :translate
end
```

Comment: It would be nice to have a look at your translate page code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass your `message` to your view.

```
post "/translate" do
    erb :translate, locals: { msg: params[:message] }
end
```

And now you can use `msg` in your view, like this:

```
<h1><%= msg %></h2>
```